# Interface realization makes my UML class diagram cluttered

Tags: uml

I model a system as my school assignment. I use database and Hibernate. I have many persistent Serializable objects. But showing that on a diagram that has approximately 20 classes makes it illegible. 
As far as I came up with a solution to split general diagram showing relationships between persistent classes and the one with interface realization. Is it the best solution or maybe there is yet better way?

Comment: Please add the homework tag for a school assignment.

Comment: I am not asking for solving my homework here, so I don't think that this tag is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

20 classes does not make it illegible, just large.  Splitting the diagram is fine.  UML is a modeling language and diagrams are just views so that is not a problem.  (However, some implementations are just views, or semi-models like Visio)  I would split across data domains, show the path which is important all on one diagram.  Focusing on showing the "use", interface, implementation all on one page.  Unless the layers are the focus.  Split on data domains, clusters of usage, and if it is all one-to-one your solution is fine.  In the future a diagram example might help.

Comment: Another common split is to have one overview diagram which shows all classes and interfaces, but without any attributes or operations, and separate diagrams each showing the guts of a group of classes. This usually works well up to a couple dozen classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the suggestion of making use of packages and perhaps composite structure diagrams.